# Why am I getting uninitialized constant FactoryGirl::Syntax (NameError) when setting gem to require: false?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot, rspec-rails

I don't want to run any Factories before I seed the database for some tests.

When I add require: false to factory_girl_rails I get the following error:

```
rails_helper.rb:37:in `block in <top (required)>': uninitialized constant FactoryGirl::Syntax (NameError)
```

Gem file:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


gem 'rails', '4.2.6'

gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'

gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

gem 'puma'

gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'redcarpet' #This gem parses markup language to HTML
gem 'devise'
gem 'email_validator'
gem 'date_validator'
gem 'rolify'
gem 'country_select'

group :development do
  gem 'web-console'
  gem 'better_errors'
end


group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'spring'
end

group :test do
  gem 'spring-commands-rspec'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', require: false
  gem 'faker'
    gem 'capybara'
  gem 'launchy'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
    gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'shoulda-matchers', require: false
end

group :production do
    gem 'pg'
    gem 'rails_12factor' 
end

ruby "2.2.3"
```

rails_helper.rb

```
# This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate rspec:install'
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
# Prevent database truncation if the environment is production
abort("The Rails environment is running in production mode!") if Rails.env.production?
require 'spec_helper'
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'shoulda_helper'
require 'shoulda/matchers'
require 'devise'
require 'support/controller_macros'


# Add additional requires below this line. Rails is not loaded until this point!

# Requires supporting ruby files with custom matchers and macros, etc, in
# spec/support/ and its subdirectories. Files matching `spec/**/*_spec.rb` are
# run as spec files by default. This means that files in spec/support that end
# in _spec.rb will both be required and run as specs, causing the specs to be
# run twice. It is recommended that you do not name files matching this glob to
# end with _spec.rb. You can configure this pattern with the --pattern
# option on the command line or in ~/.rspec, .rspec or `.rspec-local`.
#
# The following line is provided for convenience purposes. It has the downside
# of increasing the boot-up time by auto-requiring all files in the support
# directory. Alternatively, in the individual `*_spec.rb` files, manually
# require only the support files necessary.
#
# Dir[Rails.root.join('spec/support/**/*.rb')].each { |f| require f }

# Checks for pending migration and applies them before tests are run.
# If you are not using ActiveRecord, you can remove this line.
ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!

RSpec.configure do |config|
  #this allow me to not have to write FactoryGirl inside my tests
  config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods

  # Remove this line if you're not using ActiveRecord or ActiveRecord fixtures
  # config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

  # If you're not using ActiveRecord, or you'd prefer not to run each of your
  # examples within a transaction, remove the following line or assign false
  # instead of true.
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

  # RSpec Rails can automatically mix in different behaviours to your tests
  # based on their file location, for example enabling you to call `get` and
  # `post` in specs under `spec/controllers`.
  #
  # You can disable this behaviour by removing the line below, and instead
  # explicitly tag your specs with their type, e.g.:
  #
  #     RSpec.describe UsersController, :type => :controller do
  #       # ...
  #     end
  #
  # The different available types are documented in the features, such as in
  # https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs
  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!

  # Filter lines from Rails gems in backtraces.
  config.filter_rails_from_backtrace!
  # arbitrary gems may also be filtered via:
  # config.filter_gems_from_backtrace("gem name")
  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, type: :controller
  config.extend ControllerMacros,     type: :controller
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to require FactoryGirl so you can use it.

So one way would be deleting the `require: false` and the other way would be to require it in the `rails_helper.rb` using

```
require 'factory_girl_rails'
```

Comment: Both `'shoulda-matchers'` and `'factory_girl_rails'` should be required - if you use them they will be required to run the spec suite. Only use `require: false` for gems like `terminal-notifier` which should be (optionally) installed on the system but not required (loaded) by bundler.